# Summerize all fields if exists from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have different fields in the database and im fetching their values.
Now what I would like to do is subract a number if certain field exists in database.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$percent_profile_image = 40;
$percent_cover_image = 20;
$percent_profiletext = 10;
$percent_travelintext = 10;
$percent_sparetimetext = 10;
$percent_gouttext = 10;

$avatar_status_num;
$cover_status_num;
$profiletext = $display_profile['profile_text_approved'];
$sparetimetext = $display_profile['spare_time_text_approved'];
$travelintext = $display_profile['traveling_text_approved'];
$gouttext = $display_profile['go_out_text_approved'];

if($avatar_status_num == 2) { echo $percent_profile_image; } + if($avatar_status_num == 2) { echo $percent_profile_image; }
?>
```

Now I know my if code is wrong.  What I would like to do if example $avatar_status_num = 2 i would like to print out 40. if $cover_status_num = 2 I would like to substract these to numbers so. 40 + 20. So it should only print out the number and substract it if the value from DB is nr2.

I hope you understand my question :) 
Cheerz

Comment: It would help if your code showed the correct syntax on the last line. Do you want to add something? I am probably guessing correctly, but I don't really want to post a guess as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra variable to sum your values.

```
$sum = 0;
if (isset($someValue) && $someValue == 2) {
    $sum += 40;
}

if (isset($someOtherValue) && $someOtherValue == 2) {
    $sum += 20;
}
```

Or if you wanna do this dynamically in your code:

```
$percent = array(
    'profile_image' => 40,
    'cover_image' => 20,
    'profile_text_approved' => 10,
    'traveling_text_approved' => 10,
    'spare_time_text_approved' => 10,
    'go_out_text_approved' => 10,
);

$sum = 0;
foreach ($display_profile as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $percent) && $value == 2) {
        $sum += $percent[$key];
    }
}
```

**Note** In this case the `$percent` key names should be the same as the `$display_profile` key names.